# perform an action on "timeupdate" after certain time interval

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I am using html5 video and trying to store the amount of time video viewed by user for continuing the video from where it was closed.
For this I am trying to  update the database  every 5 second video was viewed I did this to get  current time every 5 seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("video#eclassvideo").on(
    "timeupdate",
      function(e){
             performaction(this.currentTime, this.duration);
    });


function performaction(currentTime, duration){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(currentTime);
        console.log(' ajax action goes here')
    },5000)
}
```

But this works only for first time it grabs after that it again continues to provide time 2-3 time per second. I tried using settimeout function during event firing but result was same. Please help me how do I get current time of video every 5 seconds only once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem .Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var player;     
var video='';
        $('#eclassvideo').bind('play',function(){
               video=document.getElementById('#eclassvideo');  
               var videotime=setInterval(function() {
               if(typeof($('#eclassvideo')[0])=='undefined'){
                        window.clearInterval( videotime); 
                        return false;
                }
                var curtime = $('#eclassvideo')[0].currentTime;
                 var duration = $('#eclassvideo')[0].duration;
                saveprogressvideo(curtime,duration);
                 }, 5000);   
               $('#eclassvideo').bind('ended',function(){
                        window.clearInterval(videotime);
                });
        });
 })

function saveprogressvideo(currenttime,duration)
{
    var timevideo=$('#eclassvideo').attr('timevideo');
    var data=$('.videocontent').data();     
    data.videolength=duration.toFixed(2);
    if(timevideo<currenttime)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'student_progress/learn_course/savevideotime',
            data:data,
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(msg){
                $('.vidmsg').html(msg);
            }
        })
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<video>` timeupdate event fires every 15-250 ms while the video plays, so your code sets multiple timeouts every **second**. If I understand what you are saying, you just want the code to run every 5 seconds, right? You would be better off setting and removing an interval whenever the video starts and stops.

```js
$(function() {
  
  var timeout
   
  $("#eclassvideo").on("playing pause", function(e) {

      // save reference
      var v = this

      // clear previous timeout, if any
      clearTimeout(timeout)

      // call immediately if paused or when started
      performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration)
      
      // set up interval to fire very 5 seconds
      if (e.type === "playing") {
        timeout = setInterval(function() {
          performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration)
        }, 5000)
      }
  })
  
  function performaction(currentTime, duration) {
    console.log(currentTime)
    console.log(' ajax action goes here')
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" id="eclassvideo" controls/>
```

You could also just revert to the timeupdate event, save a reference to the last saved currentTime, and fire `performaction()` whenever the difference  between currentTime and saved time reaches +/- 5 seconds.